# Why integral constant's possible values differs when solving $y'+2y=0$. with different approaches?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $y'+2y=0$. We can solve this equation with two methods,

1. separating  the variables $y,dy$ and $x,dx$ :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2y\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{dy}{y}=-2dx$$After integrating both sides we get $\ln|y|=-2x+c$. Which can be written as $y=e^{-2x+c}=e^c.e^{-2x}$. which is equivalent to $y=c_1e^{-2x}$ where $\large c_1>0$.

2. Solving the equation as First Order Linear Differential Equation:

$$y=e^{-2x}(\int 0\times e^{2x}dx+c')$$

Hence $y=c_2e^{-2x}$. But this time we don't have the restriction for the value of integration constant and I think it can be negative or zero too.

My question is: When we solve the same equation with different methods why the integration constant is always positive in the first case unlike the second case? ($c_1\in \mathbb{R}^+ , c_2\in \mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my mistake, in the first method we got $\ln|y|=-2x+c$ which is equivalent to

$$|y|=e^{-2x+c}=e^c.e^{-2x}$$
Hence
$$y=(\pm e^c). e^{-2x}$$So the integration constant can be either negative or positive. Furthermore we can easily verify that $y=0$ is also another solution. So the answer is $y=Ce^{-2x}$ where $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

If possible I’d avoid the first method because:

- The integral evaluates to $\ln{|y|}$ and absolute value function in general makes thing more complicated
- We divide by $y$ which requires $y\neq 0$ and we need to evaluate the case for $y=0$ separately, which makes solution inelegant

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{d}{dx}y+2y\\
\\
&=e^{2x}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}y+2e^{2x}\cdot y\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2x}\cdot y\right)\\
\\
\\
&\text{which implies}
\\
\\
e^{2x}\cdot y&=C\phantom{x},\phantom{x}C\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$